# Looking for a middle grade YA fantasy about girl who transitions into a fairy

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I've been trying to find this book for a while and I can't. From what I can remember:

- main character is a teenage girl, possibly named Alice
- She has an older brother away at college
- Single father, mother died
- When she reaches a certain age (16?) she starts a painful transition where she grows wings from her back.
- Her whole family (or i think just the mother's side) has the same thing because they are secretly fairies
- She gets feverishly sick during the process
- The wings she gets are blue?
- front cover of the book has blue fairy wings
- She may have a female best friend, name unknown
- most of the plot is very fuzzy and that's what I remember for sure

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Comment: I can't exactly remember when I read it, it was at least 5-8 years ago